# Mock an Interface and call the original method of Implementation using MOQ and C#

Tags: c#, .net, mocking, moq

I have an IEmployee Interface and there is no implementation available yet. This so happens when Multiple developers are working on the same module. Now I am writing an integration test to test my changes and would need a mock for IEmployee interface, however my test should invoke the original implementation when the method is available in the assembly dll. I am able to create an instance of the class

Interface :

```
public interface IEmployee
{
    bool IsWorkingOnDate();
    SendNotificationPreference();
}
```

Instance :

```
Type ob = Assembly.Load("MockUtility").GetType(string.Format("MockUtility.Employee");
 var Emp = (IEmployee)Activator.CreateInstance(ob);
```

Mock :

```
var bobMock = new Moq.Mock<IEmployee>();
        bobMock.Setup(x => x.IsWorkingOnDate())
           .Returns(value);
bobMock.Setup(x => x.SendNotificationPreference());
```

How can I use the above mock to call the method in the original implementation when the original implementation is not available yet.
SenNotificationPreference method returns null.

Note : I am going to write my tests for both mock and real implementation and the real implementation is called only when its available.

Comment: When the original implementation becomes available use the implementation. The mock of the interface is just being used as a stand in for the moment. No need to over complicate things,

Comment: I agree but That wasn't my requirement.
 I am just trying to build a mock testing framework that goes well with implementation and with out implementation.

Comment: If you don't have the class you can't access any implementation detail it has, so just write the test against the interface. This tests will fail until the implementation is available, which make sense actually.

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). A [mcve] should help clarify the actual problem. I would even suggest you check out AutoFixture. Trying to reinvent existing functionality is a colossal waste of time.

Comment: @MatanShahar  Please check code above(under instance) , i am able to create an instance using a string "Employee" . The implementation is not available yet, but the instance will be created when Employee class is found in the assembly.

Comment: What is `SendNotificationPreference` suppose to return. From what is shown it is not set up to return anything? Also setting up a function that depends on time with `DateTime.Now` will never work as its value is a moving target. The question in its current state appears to be missing details and thus making it unclear.

Comment: @Nkosi Alright assume that there is no DateTime.Now. That is not important. I am modifying the question to remove that parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that what you want to achieve is to call proper method while calling your mock.
Easiest way to achieve it is:

```
bobMock.Setup(x => x.SendNotificationPreference()).Callback(() => 
{
    if(isImplemented)
    {
        yourObject.YourMethod();
    }
});
```